# In a Whatsapp chat messaging journey, in the middle of the journey the contact should be able to reenter the journey and continue in loop

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have created a journey for whatsapp chat messaging with inbound chat as entry, and there are list of options to select once enters in the journey and if one option is selected there are more options under it, in here the contact should have a option to go the entry message. We tried with join but it is not working. Kindly provide a solution.

[image: Journey Flow]

Answer (score 0):

Looping joins are not allowed in Journey Builder. In our case, we ended up creating multiple journeys, one for the original keyword of inbound chat, and others with keyword matching each possible section user can make. This can simulate a loop for end user, though it forces selection keywords to be unique across all possible journeys.